# XmlReader throwing exception on file, expecting ";" instead of "=" C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, exception, xhtml, xml-parsing

I am using C# .NET, and I am scraping http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=false&multiverseid=155. The exception is being thrown on the parsing of the last line that I pasted.  It is being thrown because of the "=" in front of the first 155.  It says it is expecting a ";".  I am not that familiar with parsing xml but is there in syntax there?  And how do you go about dealing with errors on web pages if so. I am using this to set the reader up: "XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, xmlReaderSettings);" and this to read: "while (reader.Read())" and the exception is being thrown on the reader.Read().  I am also not familiar with exception handling, is there a way to skip this element because there is an issue with it and just go to the next maybe?

```
   <td id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_SubContent_SubContent_rightCol" class="rightCol">
            <div class="smallGreyMono">
                <b class="ft"><b></b></b>
                <div style="padding-left: 5px; font-size:.85em;">
                    Display: <b><a id="cardTextSwitchLink1" href='/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=false&multiverseid=155' class="selected">Oracle</a></b> | <a id="cardTextSwitchLink2" href='/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=true&multiverseid=155'>Printed</a>
```

Comment: HTML != XML don't use XmlReader. If you wan't to parse HTML use a HTML parser like http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: The `&` should be a `&amp;`, even in attribute values. HTML parsers can recover from this error which is why it works in browsers. Just like HTML parsers will ignore everything in a `<script>` element that's not the literal string `</script>`.

Comment: @nemesv You are right, another alternative could be to just download the string with webclient or a simple http request and then parse it manually.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I think I tried htmlagility but couldnt figure out how to get it going.  I'll give it another shot.  htmlagility can parse XHTML as well?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
Thats the header, also, its got javascript in it